# Proving the first Chebyshev function $\vartheta(x)=O(x)$ using prime factorisation of ${2n \choose n}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, prime-factorization, chebyshev-function

An exercise in chapter 1 of *A course in Analytic Number Theory* by Marius Overholt prompts me to find an upper bound of the binomial coefficient ${2n\choose n}$, to deduce the prime factorisation of ${2n\choose n}$, and hence to show that $\vartheta (x):=\sum_{p\leq x}\ln p =O(x)$.

Therefore, I need to show that $\vartheta (x)$ is bounded by $\ln {2n \choose n}$ in some way, for example, something like
$$
\vartheta (2n)\leq C\ln{2n \choose n} \text{ or }\vartheta (n)\leq C\ln{2n \choose n}.
$$
However, we have the prime factorisation
$$
{2n\choose n}=\frac{\prod_{p,k} p^{[2n/p^k]}}{\prod_{p,k} p^{2[n/p^k]}}=\prod_{p,k} p^{f(p,k)},
$$
where $f(p,k)=1$ if $[2n/p^k]$ is odd
, and $f(p,k)=0$ otherwise.

In some cases, this prime factorisation does **not** contain all primes smaller than $2n$. In fact, when $2n=26$,
$$
e^\vartheta(26)=223092870>10400600={26\choose 13},
$$
so the desired bound is very difficult to obtain. In fact, $10400600$ does not even have $3$ as one of its prime factor.

I thus find it very difficult to bound $\vartheta(x)$ above by $\ln {2n\choose n}$, but this seems to be the only reasonable thing to do.

**Could anyone give me a hint on this?**

Comment: the relation means $\theta(2n)-\theta(n) \le \log {2n\choose n} \le An$; since $\theta(2n)=\theta(2n+1), n \ge 2$ induction suggests itself to prove the result of the type $\theta (n) \le Bn$ as if $n=2m-1, \theta(n+1)=\theta(n) \le Bn \le B (n+1)$ but if $n=2m$, $\theta (n+1)=\theta(2m+1)=\theta(2m+2) \le A(m+1)+\theta(m+1) \le (A+B)(m+1) \le B(2m+1)$ as long as $B \ge 2A$ for example (while we fiddle with $A,B$ to ensure intiail conditions $n=1,2,3$ or so are met